# Keras - accuracy 100%, но результат не совпадает даже с тренировочным датасетом

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, keras

Есть такой код:

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy
from numpy import exp, array, random, dot

# задаем для воспроизводимости результатов
numpy.random.seed(2)

# разбиваем датасет на матрицу параметров (X) и вектор целевой переменной (Y)
X = array([[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]])

Y = array([[0, 1, 1, 0]]).T

# создаем модель, добавляем 1 слой и 3 значения для активации
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=3, activation='sigmoid'))


# компилируем модель, используем градиентный спуск adam
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])

# обучаем нейронную сеть
model.fit(X, Y, epochs = 1000, batch_size=10)

# оцениваем результат
scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
pre = model.predict(array([[0, 0, 1]]))
print(pre)
```

Как видим, значение `[0, 0, 1]` уже есть в тренировочном сете и правильное его продолжение `= 0`.

На выходе же получаю вот это:

```
accuracy: 100.00%
[[0.4054786]]
```

А должно быть, соответственно, `0`.

Как может быть при точности равной 100% неправильно предсказывать значение из тренировочного набора? Что я сделал не так?

Comment: все так, 0.40 округляется до 0. Это природа сигмоиды...

Comment: @MaxU Всмысле он когда считает accuracy, он округляет итоговое значение до ближайшего инта?

Comment: он округляет с границей 0.5 - все что меньше - `0`, все чтобольше или равно - `1`

Comment: А loss в процессе тренировки видимо достиг 0.4 примерно, так что всё сходится )

Comment: Если хотите достичь практически 100% вероятности, а не просто >0.5, то можете оптимизировать просто другую метрику, например 'mse'. Всего-то 20000 эпох и результат будет 0.00147939

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для того, чтобы предсказывать класс, вместо его вероятности воспользуйтесь методом [model.predict_classes(...)](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential#predict_classes):

```
In [33]: model.predict_classes(array([[0,0,1], [1,1,1]]))
Out[33]:
array([[0],
       [1]])
```